# Return a FileStreamResult if successful or View if unsuccessful

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, filestreamresult

In MVC, is there a way to return a FileStreamResult if my query is successful, but if not, just return the View with an error in the ViewBag. Like so....

```
    public FileStreamResult Submit()
    {
        string retVal;
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            ds = getDS();
            if (ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                ExcelXmlWorkbook book = ExcelXmlWorkbook.DataSetToWorkbook(ds);
                string fileName = "results.xml";
                book.Export(fileName, ExportFormat.Xml, 0);
                FileInfo info = new FileInfo(fileName);
                return File(info.OpenRead(), "application/x-msexcel");
            }
            else
            {
                retVal = "No Data";
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            retVal = ex.Message;
        }

        ViewBag.Result = retVal;

        return View("ViewName");
    }
```

I know this does not work, but basically, I want to open a results file if the data pull was successful... if it wasn't, I want to display the page, or redirect to a different page to show the user that the results failed. Any suggestions on a better way is also welcomed. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `ViewResult` (which is the type returned by the `View` method) and `FileStreamResult` derive from the `ActionResult` class, which represents the result of an action method, so you have to return its instance from `Submit`.

```
public ActionResult Submit()
```

Comment: @Dom Thanks for noticing. I've edited my post. Actually I made a mistake, because I wrote that `View` derives from `ActionResult`, but `View` is a method, of course :-)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! This is exactly what I was looking for. I was a victim of "the answer is so simple it's not"... Thanks again!